# How to create a named Google profile?

Tags: google, profile

According to [Google Offers Named OpenIDs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/google-offers-named-openids/) blog entry I should be able to create a named Google profile. However, going to http://www.google.com/profiles redirects me to my Google+ profile with 21 digits in the url and I don't see any option to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Google+ account, Google Profiles redirects automatically to G+ and you are not able anymore to create/set a profile. Even if you have/had a named profile, it redirects to the 21-digit Google+ profile for now. Google said it will allow Google+ named profiles in the future, but for now this option is not available.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, there's a third party service [GPlus.to](http://gplus.to) which gives a short name of form `gplus.to/<username>` and redirects to your Google+ profile